# Multiple replacements

Tags: python

I want the user to be able to input more than one character they want to remove. It works but only if one character is entered.

```
string = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
removing_chars = input("Please enter the characters you would like to remove: ")
replacements = [(removing_chars, "")]

for char, replacement in replacements:
    if char in string:
        string = string.replace(char, replacement)

print(string)
```

Comment: If either of the answers below solved your issue, then you should mark the one that best helped you as correct. This will help guide others with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're treating `removing_chars` as if it is always a single character.

For example, if `removing_chars` is `'abc'`, then `replacements` will be `[('abc', '')]`, when it should be `[('a', ''), ('b', ''), ('c', '')]` instead.

To fix this, try using a list comprehension to loop over each character in `removing_chars` and create a replacement tuple. Like this:

```
string = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
removing_chars = input("Please enter the characters you would like to remove: ")
replacements = [(char, "") for char in removing_chars]

for char, replacement in replacements:
    if char in string:
        string = string.replace(char, replacement)

print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you loop over `replacements`, `char` takes `removing_chars` as value. Then, when you check `if char in string`, Python checks if `removing_chars` is a substring of `string`. To actually remove the characters separately, you have to loop over `removing_chars` in order to get the individual characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a *combo* of [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) & [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) :

```
string = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
removing_chars = input("Please enter the characters you would like to remove: ")
​
out = string.translate(str.maketrans("", "", removing_chars))
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

#Please enter a sentence:  StacxkOverfLlow
#Please enter the characters you would like to remove:  xL
#StackOverflow
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be an excellent place to use regular expressions. We can insert the characters to remove string into aa string wrapped in `[` and `]` to create a character class, and then use `sub` to replace any occurrences of those characters with `''`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = input("line of text: ")
line of text: hello world foo bar baz
>>> r = input("characters to remove: ")
characters to remove: abc
>>> rx = re.compile(rf"[{r.strip()}]")
>>> rx
re.compile('[abc]')
>>> rx.sub('', s)
'hello world foo r z'
```

Of course, to avoid issues with special characters that are significant in regular expression character classes, you may wish to use `re.escape`. E.g.

```
>>> rx = re.compile(rf"[{re.escape('a-c')}]")
>>> rx
re.compile('[a\\-c]')
```